# using request.user.is_authenticated() in Django project

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-authentication, mongoengine

When I try to do `request.user.is_authenticated()` I get a `ValidationError: None is not a valid ObjectId`

I'm trying to track down the problem but I do not what's causing it.I'm using MongoEngine (and MongoDB.)

I have the following in my settings.py:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'mongoengine.django.auth.MongoEngineBackend',
    'rs.claimutil.auth_backend.ClaimAuthBackend',
)


SESSION_ENGINE = 'mongoengine.django.sessions'
```

This is what I get:

> Traceback: File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in get_response
>     111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "/Users/bastiano/Documents/ttsf/rsrv/views.py" in reserve
>     11.         if not request.user.is_authenticated(): File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py"
>   in inner
>     184.             self._setup() File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py"
>   in _setup
>     248.         self._wrapped = self._setupfunc() File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py"
>   in 
>     16.         request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request)) File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py"
>   in get_user
>     8.         request._cached_user = auth.get_user(request) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/**init**.py"
>   in get_user
>     101.         user = backend.get_user(user_id) or AnonymousUser() File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/django/auth.py"
>   in get_user
>     149.         return User.objects.with_id(user_id) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset.py"
>   in with_id
>     923.         return self.filter(pk=object_id).first() File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset.py"
>   in first
>     843.             result = self[0] File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset.py"
>   in **getitem**
>     1136.             return self._document._from_son(self._cursor[key]) File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset.py"
>   in _cursor
>     579.             self._cursor_obj = self._collection.find(self._query, File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset.py"
>   in _query
>     375.             self._mongo_query = self._query_obj.to_query(self._document) File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset.py"
>   in to_query
>     202.         query = query.accept(QueryCompilerVisitor(document)) File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset.py"
>   in accept
>     267.         return visitor.visit_query(self) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset.py"
>   in visit_query
>     159.         return QuerySet._transform_query(self.document, **query.query) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset.py"
>   in _transform_query
>     720.                         value = field.prepare_query_value(op, value) File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/base.py"
>   in prepare_query_value
>     455.         return self.to_mongo(value) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/base.py"
>   in to_mongo
>     451.                 self.error(unicode(e)) File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/base.py"
>   in error
>     203.         raise ValidationError(message, errors=errors, field_name=field_name)
>
> Exception Type: ValidationError at /rs/claim Exception Value: None is
>   not a valid ObjectId

Any ideas why this is happening? Is there an easier way to do user authentication in Django + MongoDB?

Views.py:

```
def claim(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return shortcuts.redirect('rs/login')
        all_b = dbutil.get_b(all=True)
        return shortcuts.render_to_response('rs/index.html',
                                             {'all_b':all_b},
                                            context_instance=template.RequestContext(request))
    elif request.method == 'POST':
```

The rest of the view is omitted for simplicity. I used ipdb to debug it and `if not request.user.is_authenticated()` is the problem. I tried using `django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required.decorator` before, but it, too, failed.

Comment: The problem was that Django was using `mongoengine.django.auth.MongoEngineBackend`and not the authentication backend I created. Even though I specified it in settings.py, I had the following line in one of my views: `r_v.obj.backend = 'mongoengine.django.auth.MongoEngineBackend'`, this, of course, forces Django to use that authentication backend. @Ross and @okm, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of my views I had the following: 
`r_v.obj.backend = 'mongoengine.django.auth.MongoEngineBackend'`, which is why Django was ignoring the AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS in settings.py, and was never using my custom authentication backend.

Answer (score 2):

Try to update your `mongoengine` to the latest version. [In master](https://github.com/hmarr/mongoengine/blob/master/mongoengine/django/auth.py#L157), it is

```
def get_user(userid):
    """Returns a User object from an id (User.id). Django's equivalent takes
    request, but taking an id instead leaves it up to the developer to store
    the id in any way they want (session, signed cookie, etc.)
    """
    # your installed mongoengine might not include following two lines
    if not userid:
        return AnonymousUser()
    return MongoEngineBackend().get_user(userid) or AnonymousUser()
```

A `userid` w/ value of `None` causes the problem, according to the trackback.

Comment: I have the latest mongoengine. I set a trace on both `get_user(userid)`and `get_user(self, userid)` and its actually using the latter - which is part of the `MongoEngineBackend`class. I thought Django was supposed to use the authentication backend I defined. Even when I comment out MongoEngineBackend in my settings, Django still uses MongoEngineBackend.

Comment: @Bastiano9 the info of the used backend is stored in session, thus commented out `MongoEngineBackend` would not have effect for a saved session. Second, what's the value of `userid` in the `get_user(userid)`?

Comment: I got rid of all the sessions stored in the db and restarted the server. I figured out the problem. In one of my views I had the following: `r_v.obj.backend = 'mongoengine.django.auth.MongoEngineBackend'`, which is why it was *never* using my custom authentication backend.

Answer (score 1):

What version of MongoEngine / Django are you using?

Have you enabled the `django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware`? That should set a `User` instance or `AnonymousUser` to the request.

What does `rs.claimutil.auth_backend.ClaimAuthBackend` look like?  And what does its `get_user` method return?  Does it stop erroring if you just have one authentication backend?

Comment: Have you enabled the `django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware`? - Yes.

I commented out the MongoEngine backend and  set an `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()`on both `authenticate()` and `get_user()` in auth_backend.ClaimAuthBackend and Django is completely skipping this backend.

Comment: so `ClaimAuthBackend` is skipped even without Mongoengine installed as a backend?

Comment: Also what versions? of mongoengine / django

Comment: I figured out the problem. See the comment below @okm's answer. Thank you so much for the excellent pointers though!